# Authenticate GET request in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, authentication

I have a PHP File that get id and remove user.like this:

```
$user_id = $_GET["id"];
remove_user($user_id); //this function remove user by that id
```

i send data to this PHP file using JQuery.like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/delete-user.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    data: "id=" + user_id,
    success: function(data) {
        location.reload();
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("Error:");
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

But I know this has a security problem.
If user enter this link in address bar:

```
http://example.com/delete-user.php?id=10
```

delete-user.php File execute and this user(with id=4) will be deleted.
how i cant prevent this?
in other words how i can check User who sent the request, do it through the form?

Comment: _"how i cant prevent this"_  - only allow it for logged in users with enough rights (admins?)

Comment: _"how i can check User who sent the request"_ - always send an authToken or whatever your login-system demands.

Comment: Start by doing some general research into how to implement authentication. This is a broad topic

Comment: you are using ajax call to delete. instead of GET use POST method thats one way apart from whats mentioned by other's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$_SESSION` to check if the user submitting the `id` is logged in and if it is, check if that user has the permission to perform this action.

But without knowing how your system / application is working, there isn't much information we can provide to you.